# Visualizing joint detection with skinned meshes and bones on threejs

Tags: three.js, 3d, blender

I am working on a project that involves visualizing the output of an AI model that detects joints and returns their X, Y, and Z coordinates. I have a human model with skinned meshes and bones that has been imported into a Three.js scene. I need to apply these coordinates to the joints of the human model in order to visualize them accurately.

I have tried changing the positions of the skinned meshes directly, but this doesn't seem to work. Instead, I need to rotate the bones one by one to achieve the desired result. However, I am facing a complex inverse kinematics problem as each bone has its own coordinate system and axes, and it's challenging to extract the rotations from the coordinates.

Is there an easier or more straightforward approach to this problem that I am overlooking?

Comment: It depends of what exactly you have to change on your target rig. In blender, being in edit mode, you can set locations (3d, of course) of each bone head and tail, not concerning too much on the rotations. In pose mode you only have rotations and scale to play with. And if you have some constraints on those joints like IK, you have to respect them too.
I have no idea, how Three.js controls its rigs, but the easiest way seems to be to add some fake targets to the rig, and with constraints make it move to desired locations. For IK targets it's straightforward, but some calc for pole targets.

Comment: The thing is that I can't directly tell my bone to move to some coordinate and expect it to output my desired pose. I also don't have any control on the joint positions directly. The joints are actually the bone ends and there are skinned meshes around them but none of them seem to be directly controllable.

Comment: It seems that it can respect some IK constraints. see e.g.  https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_skinning_ik

The idea is to set constraints' targets (and pole targets) into right positions, and let the solver handle the rest. Anyway you cannot guarantee that your input locations conform with exact length of your bones, so there would be some gap.